# Generating confidence intervals for binned data - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to generate a stylized version and regression line of an underlying dataset that is very noisy and large.  To this end, I have produced bins or varying width that attempt to equalize the number of observations in each bins like so:

```
library(mltools)

complete$mtgHours_evenBins <- bin_data(complete$mtgHoursPerUser_mean, bins=500, binType = "quantile")
```

I then get the midpoints of the bins and get new aggregated means like so:

```
complete$mtgHours_evenBins_midpoints <- midpoints(complete$mtgHours_evenBins)

#generate new aggregated means after grouping by new bins
complete <- complete %>%
            dplyr::group_by(mtgHours_evenBins) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(even_binned_rev_2016_log_mean = mean(rev_2016_log))
```

I can plot the graph like so:

```
ggplot(data = complete, aes(x = mtgHours_evenBins_midpoints, y=even_binned_rev_2016_log_mean))+
  geom_point(color='blue') +
  stat_smooth(data=complete, aes(x = mtgHours_evenBins_midpoints, y = binned_rev_2016_log_mean), 
              method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1, color = "red", se = TRUE)
```

However, irrespective of whether I use stat_smooth or geom_smooth, no confidence interval is generated.  Is this due to the fact that every observation (bin) contains an equal number of observations?  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Care to supply some sample data? We value reproducibility very highly.

Comment: Sample data can just be two columns of random numbers.  The issue is more conceptual is nature: should binned data with an equal number of observations yield a regression line without a confidence band (or rather a confidence band that is the same width as the regression line?).  If so, why does ggplot not produce it?

Comment: Whether the question is conceptual or not, it would be helpful if the demonstrating example was reproducible. What about `rev_2016_log`, `prod_2016_log` etc, are they all inconsequential? If they are, you should simplify the example.